# How to disable maximize option in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to disable maximise option in browser using javascript. 
I have tried the below code but is not working in some browsers. Is there any other option?

```
function onReady() {
window.open("https://www.google.com.au","myWindow","resizable=no");
}
```

Comment: By maximize you mean fullscreen? Or "resize browser to screen size"?

Comment: so in which browsers it worked? and in which browsers it didnt work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048935/popup-window-maximize-button

Does this help you? You can implement the answer counter wise

Comment: @Foaster I dont want the browser size to be changed.

Comment: This cannot be done through javascript, across all browsers!

Comment: This is a horrible idea and it's good it can't be done, you just can't interfere with user devices like that... If any page would do things like that I would close it and never open again... You should rather cater every resolution or point the user to the right one, when things like portrait VS landscape are your problem. But just resizing his browser window to YOUR needs is a big nonono from me and every sentient web dev...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can't do that anymore.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), the `dialog` option will do that, but it will only remove the buttons, not the menu commands for it.

```
function onReady() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com.au","myWindow","dialog=yes,resizable=no");
}
```

**But**, you can only use it with "Chrome" privileges, which you probably don't have.

---

Also be aware that if you're calling this in response to jQuery's `ready` pseudo-event as the name of the function implies, at least some browsers will prevent your code from opening that window because it's not in direct response to a user event. But if you're calling it in response to a user event, that's not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot (consistently). Deliberately malicious actions are generally restricted by browsers.

But what You can do is..

```html
window.open("mypage.html","mywindowname", "toolbar=no,menubar=no");
```

WIll give you a new window without the menubar and without the toolbar.
If you just want to disable the functionality while still showing the buttons, then you can't.

Look [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for a reference on the window.open() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.onresize = function() 
{
 window.resizeTo(500,500);
}
window.onclick = function() 
{
  window.resizeTo(500,500);
}

</script>
```